# React native TV Application not found after installation (found in system application list)

Tags: react-native

I've been created a React Native application and after installation, I don't find it in the applications list on the home screen.
When I went to see all the applications in the settings and include the system applications I can see the app under the "System Applications" section.
Why is the application treated as a system application?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have missed something in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file

in the application activity, I have updated my code to:

```
          <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:banner="@mipmap/ic_launcher" // I have added this row
                android:resizeableActivity="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>    // This row is also must
                </intent-filter>
           </activity>
```

After this change, the app did reach the home screen and got out from the "System Applications" list in the setting.